# How to redirect from view to controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my header view I wrote this code:

```
<?php 

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('instructors', array('id' => $this->session->userdata('id'))); 

    $insdatacheck = $query->row_array();

    if($insdatacheck['name'] == '') {
      redirect(base_url().'user/continueregistration');
    } else { ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">alert('test');</script>
      <?php
    }

    }

?>
```

But it does not redirect to the following page. However, if I write this in the controller, it works properly. I wrote it in header view because I want to check it in every page where enters the user. How can I improve it and write in a proper way? Thanks in advance

Comment: the correct way is to put this in the controller. A view is normally called from a controller anyway, so you'll run with the controller logic all times

Comment: but how to put this controller in that way that it must check for this code in every page where enters user?

Comment: see answer of Muhammad Usman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of your header you should put your check inside your controller constructor.

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    // if not logged-in redirect to login page
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == false) {
        redirect('login'); // where you want to redirect
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But I want this code to work on every single page. Should I write it and put this code to every function?

Comment: If you put a check in the constructor, you will have to log in to access all function of that controller.

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing you, but I didn't get it :( Can you show please or explain clearly?

Comment: Try to implement my example please if you stuck ping me I will try to help.

Comment: Should I create a new controller?

Comment: Nope! you can use in your defined controller.

Comment: Then it means that I have to include this code to all controllers, yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149644/discussion-between-muhammad-usman-and-a-aliyev).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a base controller. Place the function in the base controller and then inherit from this.

To achieve this in CodeIgniter, create a file called `MY_Controller.php` in the libraries folder of your application.

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        $user = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
        return isset($user);
    }
}
```

Then make your controller inherit from this base controller.

```
class X extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function do_something()
    {
        if ($this->is_logged_in())
        {
            // User is logged in.  Do something.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
First create session in the controller only,

Then we access session in any page,

$this->load->library('session');
$user=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');

 if (!isset($user)) { 
redirect(base_url().'user/continueregistration');
  } 
 else { 
   <script type="text/javascript">alert('test');</script>
 }
```